# How can i filter using vue-router without NavigationDuplicated

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

In my script

```
<template>
 <div >
   home page
  <button @click="queryMaking"> query making</button>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
 export default {
  data() {
   return {
     querys: []
   }
  },
  methods: {
   queryMaking(){
     this.querys.push("chemical")
     this.$router.push({
       name: 'home', query: {subject: this.querys}
     })
   }
  },
 created(){
   if (typeof this.$route.query.subject === 'string'){
     this.querys = [this.$route.query.subject]
   }else{
     this.querys = this.$route.query.subject
   }
 }
}
</script>
```

When i go to the link: http://localhost:8080/?subject=math&subject=physical. Then query another subject, i get "NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location". If i go to the link http://localhost:8080/ or with 1 query in url http://localhost:8080/?subject=math and query, i dont get anyerror. So, i need the help. Sorry for my english. Thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should catch the error like this:

```js
this.$router.push({
       name: 'home', query: {subject: this.querys}
     }).catch(() => true);
```

Comment: Then you should not navigate to the same route twice.